# Two threads (x milliseconds time for one action) in One Core == 2x time?

Tags: multithreading, cpu-architecture

I will explain the above question, I have two threads that each one of them do the same action that takes x milliseconds. if I have computer that has one core , Is it take about 2x milliseconds to do the two action ?

Comment: Thread switching itself has some overhead too so it's slightly (maybe neglibily) more than 2x.

Answer (score 2):

If the action is **[CPU-bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_bound)**, basically meaning it only consists in computations, then yes the total [wall-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) will be a bit more than twice the time take by one thread due to [context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switching) overhead.

If the action has some non negligible **[IO-related operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound)** (read from memory, disk, or network), then two threads on a single core might take a bit more than the time needed with one thread, but not necessarily twice that time. If the OS is able to [have one thread do IO while the other does computations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_management_%28computing%29#How_multiprogramming_increases_efficiency), and alternate, then you might have both threads running in the same wall time as one single thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They will be executed one after the other or somehow interleaved but it total it will take the double time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. If you have two threads and one CPU core the threads will run one after the  other, or in time slices. But it is not possible for one core to run more than one thread of execution at a time.

Unless hyperthreading is being used. But that makes one core look like two (or more) cores so that does not apply here.